# Find $ |a+b|$ knowing $|a|=4, |b|=6, |a-b|=5$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

How to find $|a+b|$ knowing $|a|=4, |b|=6, |a-b|=5$, where $a, b$ are vectors? 
I know how to do this using the parallelogram law or the law of cosines, but is there a way to do this algebraically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: Here is the parallelogram law in inner product spaces:
$2\|x\|^2+2\|y\|^2=\|x+y\|^2+\|x-y\|^2$

Answer (score 1):

Here's an algebraic approach:  (Note '$\cdot$' denotes dot product.)

$| a-b |^2=(a-b)\cdot (a-b)=|a|^2-2a\cdot b+|b|^2$

From this and the given information you can determine $a\cdot b$.

Then use $| a+b |^2=(a+b)\cdot (a+b)=...$ to find $|a+b|$